# Iterate JSON array in HTML

Tags: arrays, json, object

I want to Print this JSON in my HTML by using below code. i am little bit confused. There is nested object and array items in JSON. For more on the question you can check attached snippets for JSon data and ajax call.
Basically I am trying to make a loop of books/Tutorials from json data that contains multiple books  and tutorials.

If the json structure is wrong or a better json structure can be written the please suggest a right/better structure.

Please HELP

Thanks in advance.

```js
{
    "main_heading":"Best Firebase Tutorials & Books",
    "sub_heading":"Firebase is a Backend-as-a-Service platform that allows you to develop mobile and web application first introduced in 2011. It was acquired by Google in 2014. Here’s a list of some of the best Firebase books, courses, videos and tutorials to help you learn Firebase in 2017.",
    "tutorials":[
        {
            "0":{
                "title":"Starting with Firebase",
                "description":"Starting with Firebase by Stone River eLearning will teach you how to code a Firebase application.",
                "img_URL":"http://img.cloudimages.us/2012/06/02/computer.jpg",
                "link_URL":"#"
            },
             "1":{
                "title":"Angular and Firebase – Build a Web App with Typescript",
                "description":"Angular and Firebase – Build a Web App with Typescript by Angular University will teach you to build full-stack applications using Angular and Firebase.",
                "img_URL":"http://img.cloudimages.us/2012/06/02/computer.jpg",
                "link_URL":"#"
            },
             "2":{
                "title":"Angular 4 and Firebase 3: Create a Instagram-like portal",
                "description":"Angular 4 and Firebase 3: Create a Instagram-like portal by Essential Courses will teach you how to code and deploy a complete front-end single page application built using Angular 4 and Firebase 3.",
                "img_URL":"https://udemy-images.udemy.com/course/480x270/1283576_e198_3.jpg",
                "link_URL":"#"
            },
             "3":{
                "title":"Create a Basic Real-Time Chat App with Angular4 and Firebase",
                "description":"Create a Basic Real-Time Chat App with Angular4 and Firebase by Bluelime Learning Solutions will teach you Angular4 and Firebase by creating a real-time chat app from scratch.",
                "img_URL":"https://udemy-images.udemy.com/course/480x270/1309766_9048_3.jpg",
                "link_URL":"#"
            }
        }
    ],
    "books":[
        {
            "0":{
                "title":"Firebase Essentials",
                "description":"Firebase Essentials – Android Edition by Neil Smyth will teach everything you need to successfully integrate Firebase cloud features into your Android apps.",
                "img_URL":"https://reactdom.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/51ECBwTcOUL.SL160.jpg",
                "link_URL":"#"
            },
             "1":{
                "title":"Firebase Jumpstart",
                "description":"Firebase Jumpstart by Angular University is aimed at developers that want to get a practical understanding of the Firebase Realtime Database.",
                "img_URL":"https://reactdom.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/51zkVSwu7uL.SL160.jpg",
                "link_URL":"#"
            },
             "2":{
                "title":"Build Mobile Apps with Ionic 2 and Firebase: Hybrid Mobile App Development",
                "description":"Build Mobile Apps with Ionic 2 and Firebase: Hybrid Mobile App Development by Fu Cheng will teach you to build hybrid mobile apps using Ionic and Firebase.",
                "img_URL":"https://reactdom.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/41atb3tZPiL.SL160.jpg",
                "link_URL":"#"
            }
              
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: please write more details, how do you want print it in html?

Comment: I guess there is something left by me in the question... here is the JS part to print the vaues in HTML 
for(var i = 0; i < result.tutorials.length; i++)
{
    var tutorial = result.tutorials[i];
    var tName = result.tutorials;
    for(var j = 0; j < tutorial.versions.length; j++)
    {
        

output=result.tutorials[i].title;
    }
}

Comment: do you want to put it in a table?

Comment: no I will put the values in div which i have defined as below 
<div class='card col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 blankTarget'><div class='col-sm-3 img'><a href='http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021360.do' class='d-block' target='_blank'><img src='../../img/books/book-bidelman.png'></a></div><div class='col-sm-9'> <h5> <a href='http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021360.do' target='_blank'>"+ result.tutorials[i].title + "</a></h5><a class='btn  btn-outline-primary  btn-sm' ref='http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021360.do' target='_blank'>Learn More</a></div></div>

Comment: Check the example below!

Comment: function "json_to_html()" worked fine...

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the structur, I have removed the keys `0,1,2,3` and the direct `object {}` in `"tutorials" array and books array` see this example if that not you wanted tell me I will try yet to help you to get a solution

```js
var result={
    "main_heading":"Best Firebase Tutorials & Books",
    "sub_heading":"Firebase is a Backend-as-a-Service platform that allows you to develop mobile and web application first introduced in 2011. It was acquired by Google in 2014. Here’s a list of some of the best Firebase books, courses, videos and tutorials to help you learn Firebase in 2017.",
    "tutorials":[
            {
                "title":"Starting with Firebase",
                "description":"Starting with Firebase by Stone River eLearning will teach you how to code a Firebase application.",
                "img_URL":"http://img.cloudimages.us/2012/06/02/computer.jpg",
                "link_URL":"#"
            },
             {
                "title":"Angular and Firebase – Build a Web App with Typescript",
                "description":"Angular and Firebase – Build a Web App with Typescript by Angular University will teach you to build full-stack applications using Angular and Firebase.",
                "img_URL":"http://img.cloudimages.us/2012/06/02/computer.jpg",
                "link_URL":"#"
            },
            {
                "title":"Angular 4 and Firebase 3: Create a Instagram-like portal",
                "description":"Angular 4 and Firebase 3: Create a Instagram-like portal by Essential Courses will teach you how to code and deploy a complete front-end single page application built using Angular 4 and Firebase 3.",
                "img_URL":"https://udemy-images.udemy.com/course/480x270/1283576_e198_3.jpg",
                "link_URL":"#"
            },
            {
                "title":"Create a Basic Real-Time Chat App with Angular4 and Firebase",
                "description":"Create a Basic Real-Time Chat App with Angular4 and Firebase by Bluelime Learning Solutions will teach you Angular4 and Firebase by creating a real-time chat app from scratch.",
                "img_URL":"https://udemy-images.udemy.com/course/480x270/1309766_9048_3.jpg",
                "link_URL":"#"
            }
       ],
    "books":[
           {
                "title":"Firebase Essentials",
                "description":"Firebase Essentials – Android Edition by Neil Smyth will teach everything you need to successfully integrate Firebase cloud features into your Android apps.",
                "img_URL":"https://reactdom.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/51ECBwTcOUL.SL160.jpg",
                "link_URL":"#"
            },
             {
                "title":"Firebase Jumpstart",
                "description":"Firebase Jumpstart by Angular University is aimed at developers that want to get a practical understanding of the Firebase Realtime Database.",
                "img_URL":"https://reactdom.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/51zkVSwu7uL.SL160.jpg",
                "link_URL":"#"
            },
             {
                "title":"Build Mobile Apps with Ionic 2 and Firebase: Hybrid Mobile App Development",
                "description":"Build Mobile Apps with Ionic 2 and Firebase: Hybrid Mobile App Development by Fu Cheng will teach you to build hybrid mobile apps using Ionic and Firebase.",
                "img_URL":"https://reactdom.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/41atb3tZPiL.SL160.jpg",
                "link_URL":"#"
            }
        ]
};

for(var i in result.tutorials) { 
   var tutorial = result.tutorials[i]; 
   $('div').append('<h3>'+tutorial.title+'</h3>')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: will it work like this ? 
for(var i in result.books) { 
   var tutorial = result.books[i]; 
   $('div').append('<h3>'+book.title+'</h3>')
}

Comment: in `var tutorial = result.books[i]` change `tutorial  ` to `book` in you comment

Answer (score 0):

```js
var my_json={
    "main_heading":"Best Firebase Tutorials & Books",
    "sub_heading":"Firebase is a Backend-as-a-Service platform that allows you to develop mobile and web application first introduced in 2011. It was acquired by Google in 2014. Here’s a list of some of the best Firebase books, courses, videos and tutorials to help you learn Firebase in 2017.",
    "tutorials":[
        {
            "0":{
                "title":"Starting with Firebase",
                "description":"Starting with Firebase by Stone River eLearning will teach you how to code a Firebase application.",
                "img_URL":"http://img.cloudimages.us/2012/06/02/computer.jpg",
                "link_URL":"#"
            },
             "1":{
                "title":"Angular and Firebase – Build a Web App with Typescript",
                "description":"Angular and Firebase – Build a Web App with Typescript by Angular University will teach you to build full-stack applications using Angular and Firebase.",
                "img_URL":"http://img.cloudimages.us/2012/06/02/computer.jpg",
                "link_URL":"#"
            },
             "2":{
                "title":"Angular 4 and Firebase 3: Create a Instagram-like portal",
                "description":"Angular 4 and Firebase 3: Create a Instagram-like portal by Essential Courses will teach you how to code and deploy a complete front-end single page application built using Angular 4 and Firebase 3.",
                "img_URL":"https://udemy-images.udemy.com/course/480x270/1283576_e198_3.jpg",
                "link_URL":"#"
            },
             "3":{
                "title":"Create a Basic Real-Time Chat App with Angular4 and Firebase",
                "description":"Create a Basic Real-Time Chat App with Angular4 and Firebase by Bluelime Learning Solutions will teach you Angular4 and Firebase by creating a real-time chat app from scratch.",
                "img_URL":"https://udemy-images.udemy.com/course/480x270/1309766_9048_3.jpg",
                "link_URL":"#"
            }
        }
    ],
    "books":[
        {
            "0":{
                "title":"Firebase Essentials",
                "description":"Firebase Essentials – Android Edition by Neil Smyth will teach everything you need to successfully integrate Firebase cloud features into your Android apps.",
                "img_URL":"https://reactdom.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/51ECBwTcOUL.SL160.jpg",
                "link_URL":"#"
            },
             "1":{
                "title":"Firebase Jumpstart",
                "description":"Firebase Jumpstart by Angular University is aimed at developers that want to get a practical understanding of the Firebase Realtime Database.",
                "img_URL":"https://reactdom.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/51zkVSwu7uL.SL160.jpg",
                "link_URL":"#"
            },
             "2":{
                "title":"Build Mobile Apps with Ionic 2 and Firebase: Hybrid Mobile App Development",
                "description":"Build Mobile Apps with Ionic 2 and Firebase: Hybrid Mobile App Development by Fu Cheng will teach you to build hybrid mobile apps using Ionic and Firebase.",
                "img_URL":"https://reactdom.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/41atb3tZPiL.SL160.jpg",
                "link_URL":"#"
            }

        }
    ]
};


function json_to_html(_json){
 if(_json.main_heading){
    document.title = _json.main_heading;
 }
 if(_json.sub_heading){
        $('body').append('<h2>'+_json.sub_heading+'</h2>');
 }
 if(_json.tutorials){
  $('body').append('<h3>Tutorals</h3><div class="cls_for_tutorials" style="display: flex;" ></div>');
  var tutorials=_json.tutorials[0];
  for(var key in tutorials){
   var cur_tut='';
   cur_tut+='<label class="book" onClick="location.htef=\''+tutorials[key].link_URL+'\'">';
     cur_tut+='<label class="title">'+tutorials[key].title+'</label>';
     cur_tut+='<label class="img"><img width="175" height="150" src="'+tutorials[key].img_URL+'" border="0"></label>';
     cur_tut+='<label class="desc">'+tutorials[key].description+'</label>';
   cur_tut+='</label>';
   $('.cls_for_tutorials').append(cur_tut);

  }
 }
 if(_json.books){
   var books=_json.books[0];
   $('body').append('<h3>Books</h3><div class="cls_for_books" style="display: flex;" ></div>')
  for(var key in books){
   var cur_books='';
   cur_books+='<label class="book" onClick="location.htef=\''+books[key].link_URL+'\'">';
     cur_books+='<label class="title">'+books[key].title+'</label>';
     cur_books+='<label class="img"><img width="175" height="150" src="'+books[key].img_URL+'" border="0"></label>';
     cur_books+='<label class="desc">'+books[key].description+'</label>';
   cur_books+='</label>';
   $('.cls_for_books').append(cur_books);

  }
 }


}

json_to_html(my_json);
```

```css
      .book{
        display:inline-block;
        border-style:solid;
        border-color:gray;
        border-radius:4px;
        border-width:2px;
        width:200px;
        height:500px;
        margin:10px;
        cursor:pointer;
      }
      .title{
        display:block;
        height:100px;
        margin:10px;
        font-weight:bold;
        cursor:pointer;
      }
      .img{
        display:block;
        height:150px;
        width:175px;
        margin:10px;
        cursor:pointer;
      }
      .desc{
        display:block;
        height:200px;
        margin:10px;
        cursor:pointer;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```